# Oracle validate XML through XSD: ORA-04030: out of process memory when trying to allocate 1032 bytes

Tags: xml, oracle, xsd

I am trying to validate an XML through XSD using Oracle PL/SQL. It works on smaller files, but not with bigger ones. I get the following error:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVu7m.png): ORA-04030: out of process memory when trying to allocate 1032 bytes (qmxlu subheap,qmemNextBuf:alloc)

I search and it is supposed to be because of the parameter PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET, which according to our DBAs it is:

```
pga_aggregate_target                 integer  0
```

As can be seen it is unlimited and the xml file I am trying to validate is 500 MB.

What is causing this error? How can I fix it?

Here is my code, my expected output is "valid":

```
DECLARE
   v_schema_url   VARCHAR2 (200) := 'Test.xsd';
   v_blob         BLOB;
   v_clob         CLOB;
   v_xml          XMLTYPE;
   xml_file BFILE;
   xmlClob CLOB;

   src_offset number := 1 ;
   dest_offset number := 1 ;
   lang_ctx number := DBMS_LOB.DEFAULT_LANG_CTX;
   warning integer;
   res integer;
BEGIN
   dbms_xmlschema.deleteschema(v_schema_url); 
   DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.registerschema (schemaurl   => v_schema_url,
                                  schemadoc   => bfilename ('DIR_XSD','Test.xsd'),
                                  local       => TRUE);
   xml_file := BFILENAME('DIR_XSD', 'test.xml');
   DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(xmlClob, true);
   DBMS_LOB.FILEOPEN(xml_file, DBMS_LOB.FILE_READONLY);
   DBMS_LOB.LOADCLOBFROMFILE(xmlClob, xml_file, DBMS_LOB.LOBMAXSIZE, src_offset,
                             dest_offset, DBMS_LOB.DEFAULT_CSID, lang_ctx, warning);

   v_xml := XMLType.createXML(xmldata=>xmlClob,schema=>v_schema_url);

   DBMS_LOB.FILECLOSEALL();
   DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(xmlClob);

   v_xml.schemaValidate(); --it fails here

   IF v_xml.isschemavalid (v_schema_url) = 1 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('valid');
   ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('not valid');
   END IF;
END;
```

Comment: PGA target of zero does not mean unlimited; [see the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams157.htm#REFRN10165). Your DBA needs to look at other memory settings too.